# How can I link to the source of a .rst file in BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket

When I make a link to a .rst file in my repo, it is rendered, which is nice, but means I can't link to a specific line in the file: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/src/fee2fd97520c0bea5a5e58e54cd7d0b23dcc0dd2/CHANGES.rst?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

The `fileviewer` option seems to be what I need to change, but I can find no mention of any fileviewer other than `file-view-default`.

How can I link to specific line in a .rst file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can link to a specific line in an RST file on Bitbucket. It gets rendered to HTML.

But you *can* link to a particular *heading*. For example, here is a link to the version 3.0 heading: https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/src/fee2fd97520c0bea5a5e58e54cd7d0b23dcc0dd2/CHANGES.rst?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#rst-header-version-3-0-2009-06-13

Simply right-click the heading and "inspect element". Find the `id` of the element to which you want to link, and append that `id` to the URL with a `#` (here I used the `rst-header-version-3-0-2009-06-13` `id`).